# Install MVC on 2.0.NET Server with IIS6 without Admin Rights

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-2.0, iis-6, installation, windows-server-2003

On my local machine using IIS 5 (winxp) and visual Web Developer, I've built a beautiful and well composed website using MVC.
Now to deploy to the testing server. I find out that it does not have MVC installed - 
**Error:-**

---

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

***Line 39:***               add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions,Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/
**Line 40:**                add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

> **Line 41:***              *add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

Source File: web.config    Line: 41

---

Because of companies unfamiliarity with IT and programming they are reluctant to allow admin rights or install anything that they do not get suggested by their contracted guru, who just isn't an mvc fan. So I prefer a solution that is similiar to relocating some DLLs or importing another project.

***HOW CAN I USE MVC on IIS6 2.0.net???***

I've read 
install-asp-net-mvc-without-administrator-rights
~which applies to IIS 7
asp-net-mvc-on-iis6
~ does not address installation or running the appliaction
I am aware of the routing issues once installed. I will use wildcard routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Jason White says is right ... you have to have .NET 3.5 to use ASP.NET MVC. However, if you want to get into crazy, unsupported, hack-ish territory, it is possible to run ASP.NET MVC against .NET framework 2.0. I SERIOUSLY don't recommend it, but if you want to look into it, [Scott Hanselman talks about it here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Bin Deploying ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx).

But you still will need to have .NET 3.5 installed on that server.