# running asp.net mvc on iis6, do I need to install anything on the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

running asp.net mvc on iis6, do I need to install anything on the server?
or can I just drop the .dll's in the /bin (system.web.mvc/routing/etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some resources for running MVC on IIS6:

Have to have .NET 3.5 to use ASP.NET MVC (without hacking):
[Install MVC on 2.0.NET Server with IIS6 without Admin Rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690864/install-mvc-on-2-0-net-server-with-iis6-without-admin-rights)

And 
http://www.developingfor.net/aspnet-mvc/deploying-aspnet-mvc-on-iis6.html

Setup the Routing to work with IIS6:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

And

http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

Running it on .Net 2.0 Framework:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) walkthrough and [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/06/30/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-6-solve-404-compression-and-performance-problems.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Should just be able to drop the dlls into the bin.  but you do have to do some work within your global.asax file with regards to the rounting to make it work under IIS6.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I had to wrap all links in Url.Content like below.

For IIS 6 to properly parse the paths